# How to format text written to a variable?

Tags: django, django-views

I am get the text from the database. He comes in the following form.

```
city = City.objects.first()
#London
country = Contry.objects.first()
#UK
metatag = MetaTag.objects.first()
#text {city.name} else text {country.name}
```

screen of note from database
[image]

How can I format it?

Need to get:

*text London else text UK*

Comment: Where do you wish to format it - in your view or template and what are you formatting it. It's not really clear to me.

Comment: I would like to format in view.

Comment: The string `text {city.name} else text {country.name}` is written to `metatag`. It is necessary to substitute the appropriate variables.

Comment: what you want to format ? your question is not clear ?

Answer (score 0):

```
metatag.format(city_name=city.name, country_name=country.name)
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a more flexible solution?